# Java: What would happen if multiple threads are trying to access a queue implemented from LinkedList as opposed to ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

What would happen if multiple threads are trying to access a queue implemented from `LinkedList` as opposed to `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`?

Assuming that each thread only uses `add()` and `poll()` and no other function calls, are those two operations atomic?

If they are atomic, then is there a benefit in using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead of a regular `LinkedList` implementation?

Comment: The javadoc of `LinkedList` itself is enough to answer the question; it specifically says: "Note that this implementation is not synchronized.". What else do you need to know? In other words: go with the other one :p

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined. A regular `LinkedList` is not atomic / safe for a multi-threaded use.

You can wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedList(LinkedList)` to gain atomic operations but it's still different. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` was specifically designed for use in a multi-threaded environment as "An unbounded thread-safe queue based on linked nodes". And you'll find several things it does differently if you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) like

> implementation employs an efficient non-blocking algorithm [...]

while a synchronized `LinkedList` locks the entire list for every operation. But it also has downsides like

> Beware that, unlike in most collections, the size method is NOT a constant-time operation.

It depends on your requirements but if you want a concurrent queue, it's pretty safe to assume that you shouldn't use a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

Those operations are not atomic.
Looking at the source for LinkedList you can see add and poll call routines that are most definitely not safe for two threads to be executing on the same instance without synchronization.